# How to set Webpack 5 in Next.js to use a WASM library compiled for Node.js?

Tags: rust, next.js, webassembly, webpack-5, wasm-pack

### Context

I developed a library called *wasmetric-crypto* in Rust using *wasm-bindgen* and *wasm-pack*.
On the other hand, I developed a web app with Next.js 12.1 and installed locally via npm wasmetric-crypto.
I compiled wasmetric-crypto to the **Node.js target** because I’d like to use this library **into the API Routes** of my web app and a dependency of this library ([rand crate](https://docs.rs/rand/latest/rand/)) imports the module [crypto](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html) from Node.js.

### Problem

In the wasmetric-crypto source code a function called `encrypt` calls to the function `rand::thread_rng()` and internally it imports the module *crypto* from Node.js to perform some operations. But when I execute the Next.js app the WASM file is not found by its JS file and my app crashes.
Note that compile wasmetric-crypto to the **bundler target is not a solution** because the previous error is not reproduced anymore but when I call to the wasmetric-crypto function `encrypt`, the web app crashes with the error `could not initialize thread_rng: Node.js crypto module is unavailable` because the *rand crate* tries to import *crypto* but it wasn't compiled for Node.js so the module is not available.

### Expected solution

Configure Webpack to copy the WASM file (keeping the original filename) next to the JS file that reads it.

### Attachments

**wasmetric-crypto/Cargo.toml**

```
[package]
name = "wasmetric-crypto"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["David Ignacio Espinoza Saavedra"]
edition = "2021"

[lib]
crate-type = ["cdylib", "rlib"]

[features]
default = ["console_error_panic_hook"]

[dependencies]
# Enable JS feature for getrandom to support wasm32-unknown-unknown
getrandom = { version = "^0.2.5", features = ["js"] }
js-sys = "^0.3.56"
rsa = "^0.5.0"
rand = { version = "^0.8.5", features = ["getrandom"] }
sha2 = "^0.10.2"
wasm-bindgen = "^0.2.79"
console_error_panic_hook = { version = "^0.1.7", optional = true }
wee_alloc = { version = "^0.4.5", optional = true }

[dev-dependencies]
wasm-bindgen-test = "^0.3.29"

[profile.release]
opt-level = "s"
```

**wasmetric-crypto/lib.rs**

```rs
pub fn encrypt(&self, data: &Uint8Array) -> JsResult<ArrayBuffer> {
    match &self.public_key {
        Some(public_key) => {
            let mut rng = rand::thread_rng(); // Error is raised here
            // Some code
        }
        None => Err(JsError::new("The public key was not set to this instance")),
    }
}
```

**wasmetric-crypto/pkg/wasmetric_crypto.js**

```js
// Snippet of code generated by wasm-pack where the WASM file is read
const path = require('path').join(__dirname, 'wasmetric_crypto_bg.wasm');
const bytes = require('fs').readFileSync(path);

const wasmModule = new WebAssembly.Module(bytes);
const wasmInstance = new WebAssembly.Instance(wasmModule, imports);
wasm = wasmInstance.exports;
module.exports.__wasm = wasm;
```

**app/package.json**

```json
{
  "name": "ferrisdrive_file-repository",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "next": "^12.1.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "wasmetric-crypto": "file:../vendor/wasmetric-crypto/pkg",
  }
```

**app/next.config.js**

```js
module.exports = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  webpack: (config, { buildId, dev, isServer, defaultLoaders, webpack }) => {
    config.experiments = {
      asyncWebAssembly: true,
      layers: true,
    };
    return config;
  },
};
```

**app/pages/api/files/index.js**

```js
import { WASMetricCrypto } from "wasmetric-crypto";
async function encryptSignature(signature) {
  const publicKeyBuffer = await fs.readFile("secrets/key.pub");
  const crypto = WASMetricCrypto.withPublicKey(
    bufferToUint8Array(publicKeyBuffer, publicKeyBuffer.byteOffset)
  );
  return crypto.encrypt(bufferToUint8Array(signature, signature.byteOffset)); // Call to encrypt from WASM
}
```

This is the [.next folder generated by Webpack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1oaeV.png) and `wasmetric_crypto_bg.wasm` should be located next to `files.js` because that JS file reads the WASM file when the app is bundled.

> Some other ideas to resolve my problem are welcome